Show that $(i-1)^{8k}$ is a natural number

Let $z = i - 1\in\mathbb{C}$. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Show that $z^n \in\mathbb{N}$ when $n$ is divisible by $8$.

I note that $z$ can be written as
$$z = \sqrt{2}(\cos(\arctan(-1)) +  i \sin(\arctan(-1))) = \sqrt{2}\left(\cos\left(- \frac{\pi}{4}\right) + i \sin\left(- \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)$$
Now, using De Moivre's thereom, which states that $(\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta))^{n}=\cos(n\theta) + i \sin(n\theta)$,
$$z^{n} =  \left(\sqrt{2}\left(\cos\left(- \frac{\pi}{4}\right) + i \sin\left(- \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)\right)^{n}
= \sqrt{2}^{n}\left(\cos\left(-\frac{n\pi}{4}\right) + i \sin\left(- \frac{n\pi}{4}\right)\right)$$
For $n$ increasing by $8$, $n = 8k$, where $k$ is natural number. Thus
$$z^{n} = \sqrt{2}^{8k}\left(\cos\left(-\frac{8k\pi}{4}\right) + i \sin\left(- \frac{8k\pi}{4}\right)\right).$$
Since $\cos\left(-\frac{8k\pi}{4}\right) = \cos(-2k\pi) = \cos(0) = 1$ and $\sin\left(- \frac{8k\pi}{4}\right)= \sin(-2kπ) = \sin(0) = 0$, $z^{n} = \sqrt{2}^{8k}$ is indeed a natural number for $n$ increasing by $8$.
Is my proof valid? Can I make any improvements anywhere? I have not constructed many proofs yet, and will gladly welcome any feedback and critique!

Looks good to me

Probably much simpler to explicitly calculate $(i-1)^4=-4$ through repeated (just twice!) squaring. $((i-1)^2)^2=(-2i)^2=-4$

You could also say $(i-1)^2=-2i$, so $(i-1)^4=-4$, so $(i-1)^8=16\in\mathbb N
$, so $(1-i)^{8n}=16^n\in\mathbb N$
(typed while @Malady’s comment appeared)

A slightly shorter way to write your solution would be $$(i-1)^{8k}=\left(\sqrt{2}e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}i}\right)^{8k}=(\sqrt{2})^{8k}e^{-\frac{8\pi k}{4}i}=16^ke^{-2\pi k i}=16^k\in\mathbb{N}$$

Formatting note:  use \sin, \cos, etc.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so..

a tip: using $re^{\iota \theta}$ notation for complex numbers is useful in case of dealing with multiplications and powers

Your proof looks valid, though you could simply say $(i-1)^2=-2i$, so $(i-1)^4=-4$, so $(i-1)^8=16\in\mathbb N$, so $(i-1)^{8k}=16^k\in\mathbb N$.

In polar coordinates
Set $z:=re^{i\phi}=(1-i) ^{8k};$
The interesting part is arg$(z);$
arg $(i-1)= 135°;$
arg $((i-1)^{8k}) =8k \cdot 135°$
$=k \cdot 1080°= k (3 \cdot 360°)=$
$(3k) \cdot 360°, $
and we are almost done.
As usual I read only half the question.
Need to show that $(\sqrt{2})^8$ is a natural number (Thanks, Lee Mosher), not just real as I had in mind.
$((2)^{1/2})^8=2^4.$

I agree that the interesting part is $arg(z)$, and unlike other answers this is my answer of choice. But you're not quite done because you do still need to raise $r = \sqrt{2}$ to the 8th power.

What I like particularly about this answer is that no calculation is actually needed. On just needs to visualize the complex vector $1-i$.

Lee. Thank you for your comments.

Your proof is correct, although it definitely isn't the shortest or more elegant. Isn't it easier to prove that $(i - 1)^8 = 16$?
